# ListContourPlot not behaving as expecting, contours do not match up with data

Tags: plotting

I'm currently doing some data analysis and I'm struggling to get ListContourPlot to work as expected. Here is a MatrixPlot of my data (just a list of lists):

[image]

By eye it seems like adding contours to this plot shouldn't really pose much of a problem, but doing ListContourPlot on the same data and overlaying it over the MatrixPlot, I get the following:

[image]

Clearly the contours are not following lines of constant colour; can anyone give me any hints as to what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the option [`DataReversed -> True`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataReversed.html) to `MatrixPlot`:

```
data = Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}];

lcp = ListContourPlot[data, ImageSize -> 300, ContourShading -> None];
mp1 = MatrixPlot[data, ImageSize -> 300];
mp2 = MatrixPlot[data, ImageSize -> 300, DataReversed -> True];

Row[{lcp, mp1, mp2}]
```

[image]

```
Row[Show[mp1, lcp], Show[mp2, lcp]]
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for the help! Is there any option to do the exact same operation to the ListContourPlot, so that I can keep the data ordered in the way it's ordered in the MatrixPlot?

Comment: @alex1stef2, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: ... Re "same operation for `ListContourPlot`.." : you can reverse the rows of the input matrix: `ListContourPlot[Reverse@data, ImageSize -> 300, 
 ContourShading -> None]`